# How to design an Invite model with additional data if the user does not exist in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am unsure about the correct implementation for the following problem, while designing an e-signing service:

1. There is a Contract entity
2. There is a ContractRecipientEvent entity, which is created using through m2m table.

Here is code for those models:

```
class Contract(AbstractModelBase):
owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="contracts")
contract_signing_date = models.ForeignKey(ContractSigningDate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
contract_signing_type = models.CharField(
    max_length=64,
    choices=ContractSigningType.choices,
    default=ContractSigningType.SIMPLE
)
recipients = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="ContractRecipientEvent", related_name="contracts_from_events")
```

Then there is **ContractRecipientEvent**:

```
class ContractRecipientEvent(AbstractModelBase):
contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contract_to_person')
recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='person_to_contract')
role = models.CharField(
    max_length=64,
    choices=ContractRecipientAction.choices, default=ContractRecipientAction.SIGN
)
message = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
recipient_signing_status = models.CharField(
    max_length=64,
    choices=ContractRecipientSigningStatus.choices,
    default=ContractRecipientSigningStatus.NOT_SIGNED,
    blank=True,
)
```

As you can see ContractRecipientEvent has references to both Contract and User. It works well if the User is already created. The problem is that I need the following behavior:

The Contract Serializer should only accept recipients' emails. Those emails will most likely be of the new users, who are not registered in the system so that **they don't have a User entity**.

I think that I need to create a separate Invite model, which would have an email field. Then I could check after user registration for which contract he was invited to, delete the Invite record, and assign a new User for the Contract.

However, where should I put current fields from the ContractRecipientEvent e.g: **role, message, recipient_signing_status** (which would be updated, once the User will sign a contract)? Should they be put inside of the Invite? If so, then I would need to create ContractRecipientEvent and **copy the data from the Invite model**. That seems like a bad design choice.

I would welcome any helpful suggestions or critiques :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `Invitation` and `InvitationSign` model which includes some fields, such as: email, accepted/declined (if user can accept and decline the invitation was sent), signedup (True/False), inviter/invitee, etc.

When you implement all requirements about sending the invitation to the user who is not yet registered before by email, you need to handle `accepting/declining/sharing/... data` in the User model (after saving the User instance).

Bellow is example about `InvitationSign` model:

```
class InvitationSign(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "invitation sign"
        verbose_name_plural = "invitation sign"

    invitation = models.OneToOneField(
        to=Invitation,
        related_name="sign",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    sign_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=SIGN_TYPES,
        default=SIGN_DEFAULT_TYPE
    )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Sign for {}".format(self.invitation)
```

Comment: Thanks! So it is correct for me to include: role, message, recipient_signing_status and etc. inside of the Invitation model. And then, copy that data from Invitation and create an m2m model ContractRecipientEvent?

Comment: The invitation model is a place to store information about your invitation, such as at least some fields: email, accepted, declined?
For your case: in User model, for every registering a new user, you should filter all the records in Invitation model for handling signing the Contract.

Comment: Yes, but where should I store these details:  role, message, recipient_signing_status and etc. They are all related to ContractRecipientEvent, however, I can't create m2m model ContractRecipientEvent, before the User is not created, because ContractRecipientEvent has foreign key to the User

Comment: I see. You can store any information about the invitation in the `Invitation` model. If you feel the Invitation store many fields, you can also create the `InvitationSigning` related to `Invitation` by using one-to-one relationship for storing these details: role, message, recipient_signing_status and etc.

Comment: Yes, I thought about creating a one-to-one model InvitationSigning. Still, I would need to copy data from InvitationSigning to pass all required data to the ContractRecipientEvent. I would like to have some kind of swapping feature. That way I could just swap the foreign key of InvitationSigning from the Invitation to the ContractRecipientEvent. Perhaps there is a way? :)

Comment: Yah, you can store the content_object of the Contract for handling signing after user creates the account. That is the best way.

Comment: I have added the example model to my answer, hope you can see!

Comment: Hello again, just before accepting the answer I tried to implement it. The issue is, that if user already registered I don't need to create Invitation. User will be automatically assigned to sign a contract in my case. Should I make invitation field as null and blank to make it work? Or should I refactor code even more?

Comment: Keep the old workflow and use `signed_up` field in `Invitation` model for sending (or don't send) the invitation to users as well.